# Strange behavior with PHP 'and' operator

Tags: php

I am having trouble understanding the behavior of the 'and' PHP operator.

Here is the code:

```
$condition1 = true;
$var2 = "var2";
$var3 = "var3";

$condition2 = $condition1 and $var2 == $var3;

if($condition2)
    echo '$condition1 and $var2 == $var3';
```

Output: $condition1 and $var2 == $var3

Now it is obvious that since `$var2 != $var3`, `$condition2` should be false. Hence the `echo` statement should not be executed but it happens the other way. Can any one tell me what's wrong with this code?

Comment: What about `$condition2 = ($condition1 == true) && ($va2 == $var3);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `&&` instead of `and`.

`and` has lesser precedence than `&&`. The statement

`$condition2 = $condition1 and $var2 == $var3;`

is executed in two steps from left to right.

1: `$condition2 = $condition1` is executed. i.e. `$condition2` is `true` now.

2: `$var2 == $var3;` is executed which performs the evaluation but does not assign any value to any variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an operator precedence issue. Try this instead:

```
$condition2 = ($condition1 and $var2 == $var3);
```

I think the issue is that your current code gets interpreted like this:

```
($condition2 = $condition1) and ($var2 == $var3)
```

Comment: See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php for operator precedence (also confirming @nad's approach of using `&&` instead).

Answer (score 2):

Try this
    $condition2 = ($condition1 and $var2 == $var3);
Or this one
    $condition2 = ($condition1 && $var2 == $var3);